# What do the highlighted keywords in Visual Studio mean?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

When you type `if`, Visual Studio shows a context menu:

[image: Context Menu]

Then when you hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, that will be expanded:

[image: Highlighting]

The keyword “true” is highlighted. What does this highlighting mean?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx

Comment: for what i understand of what you posted...it's called intellisense, and the true on the if is how it is defined per template, it's expecting for you to supply the actual test condition.

Comment: Hi Anas, does your issue is solved or not? For your current issue, the reply that CodingYoshi looks reason, do you have any other questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are called [Code Snippets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx).

The highlight means that if you continue typing, it will go into the highlighted section.

For example, if you type "if" then TAB TAB, you will get this:

```
if (true)
{

}
```

and `true` will be highlighted. If you continue typing, `true` will be replaced with whatever you are typing such as a condition like `x == 2` etc.

They are especially handy if there were more parameters, you type and press TAB and it will go to the next highlighted section.